# Convert Date type that looks like this 1964-01-08 00:00:00 to just 1964-01-08

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using Mode Analytics.

I have a date that looks like this:
1964-01-08 00:00:00

When I use

`select typeof(dob)`

I get that it's a `date` type.

**Desired Output:**
1964-01-08

What I've tried:

`DATE(date_parse(CAST(the_date as varchar), '%Y-%m%-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'))`

Error: Invalid format: "1964-01-08" is too short

`DATE(the_date)`

Result: The same

I'm not sure what else to try - does anyone have a solution in mind?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: use
DATE_FORMAT(your_date_here, '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Maybe a little explanation too...